# how to set up and use a Rails routes prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When running rake routes I see:

```
 Prefix   Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
 articles  GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
```

along with some others I left out.

This is because my routes.rb file has:

```
resources :articles
```

My question is what exactly is this Prefix, and how would I change it?

From my understanding it is a shortcut to the URI, so in my app I could just refer to new_article instead of articles/new? Do I really refer to @new_article or is there some other format to reference it.

Second question, how do I edit that? Lets say I want a prefix called new_document instead of new_article for the get request on that url. What would I put in my routes.rb file?

[I looked at this link from the rails guides but all it seems to show is how to make the url longer by adding a prefix in front of it.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Paths**

I'm not sure why it's called `prefix` - it should be called `path helper`:

[image]

The bottom line is when you call helpers like `link_to` or `form_tag` etc - they will require `paths` to populate different actions in your app's routing structure.

As Rails favours [`convention over configuration`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) & [DRY programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), meaning if you can reference these `path helpers` over using standard `urls`, it will allow you to make one reference & chance the route as required

EG

Calling `articles_path` is *far* more powerful than referencing `/articles` every time

---

**Routes**

To answer your question properly, you will need to appreciate Rails uses [`resourceful` routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes) - basically meaning that every `route` helper you create *should* be defined around any resource in your application

Due to the MVC structure of Rails, these resources will typically be defined by the `controllers` you use:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles #-> articles_path etc
```

You should always reference your resources as they are (in your case `articles`).

To customize the path helper, you'll need to *change* the reference in the routes file, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :articles, as: :document, path: "document" #-> domain.com/documents
```

This allows you to define custom routes / path helpers, allowing you to call those as you wish

Answer (score 24):

It let's you use shortcuts such as `new_article_path` or `new_article_url` in your controllers and views. These come in very handy when doing things like redirecting users to a specific page or generating dynamic links.

You can change the prefix by adding the `as:` option in your routes.rb file. For example:

```
GET '/new', to: 'articles#new', as: 'my_new_article`
```

This would change the prefix to `my_new_article`.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use [route scopes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for it. In your `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Any other routes here
  scope 'admin' do
    resources :articles
  end
end
```

`/admin/articles` and all the other CRUD related routes will work with `link_to`, form submit controls, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You're right, the prefix is used in building the named routes, so the `resources method` in the routes file creates routes like `articles_path, new_article_path` etc. To refer to a route in your code, add `path` to the prefix that you see when `running rake routes`.

If you want to change the prefixes generated by the resources method in your routes file, use the **`:as option`**, like this:

**`resources :articles, as: :posts`**

This will generate routes like 'new_post_path' that you can use in your views.

If you want to change the path of the route in the browser, you can use the `path` option:

```
resources :articles, path: :posts
```

Which will generate routes like `/posts/1 or /posts/new` instead of `/articles/1 or /articles/new`, but the routes will still be named `articles_path, new_article_path` etc in your code. You can use both `:path and :as` options to change both the `path and the prefix` of your resource routes.

To change a basic route in your routes file, you can simply use `:as`, like so:

**`get 'messages' => 'messages#index', as: :inbox`**

This will create the route inbox_path which you can use in your code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The prefix can be used with the route helpers to generate routes in your application. So in your application, the articles_path helper generates a route for articles index page, new_article_path is the route for the new article page, and article_path(@article) would be the route for the show page for @article.

To specify a different route, you could change your routes.rb file to:

```
resources :articles, as: :documents
```

That will give you:

```
documents  GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
new_document GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
```

I might consider changing the resource name to documents as it can get confusing when you rename routes and get a mix of terminology between the route and the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
resources :articles do
 collection do
      get  "new"  => "articles#new",  :as => 'new_document'
 end
end
```

and you can use it:

```
link_to "New foo", new_document_path
```

or

```
link_to "New foo", new_document_url
```

url prints the absolute url (http://server.com/controller/action) meanwhile path prints the relative url (`/controller/action`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try in config.ru file

```
 map 'YOUR_PREFIX_HERE' do
   run Rails.application
 end
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the assets, at least in dev