# How do rails forms work without a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to challenge my learning by creating a simple project using rails forms, however I have gotten really stuck and can't find any information that seems to help online.

**What I am trying to do:**

I want to create a rails application with no model (so no persistence of data). Simply put I want a user to enter a Soundcloud URL which then gets transferred to the controller where I can do more logic. Essentially I am really trying to understand the connection between the Rails form and the controller in rails. I have spent all day reading about HTML forms, as well as googling this exact question without really fully getting it.

I understand there are different form helpers, but what I cannot seem to understand is how to use these without a model. My biggest hang up right now is I cannot get the form values transferred to the controller. I thought I understood RESTful routes, PUT/GET etc.. but this has made me super frustrated that I cannot seem to get my head around this. Any advice is super appreciated.

**The code:**

Below is the specific code I am struggling with, currently when I get submit the form it crashes giving me an error based on routes, and that's where I am stuck.

Problem code is found in the `_form.html.erb` file in views:

```
<%= form_tag '/show' do %>
  <%= label_tag(:soundcloud_url, "Please enter a valid Soundcloud Artist URL:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:soundcloud_url) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Let's go!") %>
<% end %>
```

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :soundcloud_query

  root 'soundcloud_query#index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/show"
```

rake routes output:

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
soundcloud_query_index GET    /soundcloud_query(.:format)          soundcloud_query#index
                       POST   /soundcloud_query(.:format)          soundcloud_query#create
  new_soundcloud_query GET    /soundcloud_query/new(.:format)      soundcloud_query#new
 edit_soundcloud_query GET    /soundcloud_query/:id/edit(.:format) soundcloud_query#edit
      soundcloud_query GET    /soundcloud_query/:id(.:format)      soundcloud_query#show
                       PATCH  /soundcloud_query/:id(.:format)      soundcloud_query#update
                       PUT    /soundcloud_query/:id(.:format)      soundcloud_query#update
                       DELETE /soundcloud_query/:id(.:format)      soundcloud_query#destroy
                  root GET    /                                    soundcloud_query#index
```

Github link:

https://github.com/gaelant/simple_soundcloud_app/commit/09c4c4df524bb721a0f472b4378cd8c1ff18177f

Note: I understand this is a basic question but I have just gotten really confused with this. I know the way the code above is written is not correct, but I have tried so many different things and I just don't understand what is going on, or if this is even possible without a model.

Comment: Please add your entire error and the relevant sections of `routes.rb` (since you are, apparently, getting a routing error) to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, added the requested details.

Comment: to get correct route url use call `rails routes`

Comment: Oh, right. Forms do a `post` and you're trying to use the `/show` url. If you do `rake routes` in your console, you'll see that you don't have a routes for `post :show`. You're `/create` url will accept a `post`.

Comment: Hey there! So I tried putting create in but I got this:
No route matches [POST] "/create"

To see my detailed output of the rake routes I put it in the question above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `/show` form action points to nowhere. `rails routes` shows you which url is valid and to which `controller#action` each of them lead.

The correct form action would be

```
<%= form_tag '/soundcloud_query' do %>
  <%= label_tag(:soundcloud_url, "Please enter a valid Soundcloud Artist URL:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:soundcloud_url) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Let's go!") %>
<% end %>
```

A far more better way is to use the url_helpers available through your defined ressource in `Routes.rb`

Doing so your form action would look like this

```
<%= form_tag soundcloud_query_index_path do %>
  <%= label_tag(:soundcloud_url, "Please enter a valid Soundcloud Artist URL:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:soundcloud_url) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Let's go!") %>
<% end %>
```

The hardcoded and the url_helper based solution will route your request to a controller class named `SoundcloudQuery` where the action `create` will be called. Inside this action you have to put all needed logic.

It's also possible do define that `/show` should point to a specifc controller and action. This would look like this.

```
post '/show', to: 'mycontroller#myaction', as: 'mypathnameforhelper'
```

A much more better explanation with many examples about routes and how to use them can be found in this quite good guide.

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

**Hint:** You should stay close to the ROR naming conventions. Controllers should have pluralized names. So you should define your routes like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ressources :soundcloud_queries

  root 'soundcloud_queries#index'
end
```

and then rename your controller class and file accordingly into `SoundcloudQueries` and `soundcloud_queries.rb`. But this is not mandatory.

Comment: Hey Tekkla! WOW this helped me so much. I have got it working now (and renamed my controller, DOH...thanks for pointing that out).

I am still confused about this line in particular (which got everything working for me): `<%= form_tag soundcloud_queries_path do %>` . If I understand this correctly, it will make a POST request to the soundcloud_queries controller path. Implicit in this is 'rails magic' that it knows already to look for a create action inside the controller? I am just so confused how little I specify yet how much actually happens in such a specific way.

Comment: BTW I will mark this as answered. Thanks for your time Tekkla. Also, I have read the rails routing link but sadly I don't think it really helped me understand the routing as much, as I read it - it makes sense - but then I go to apply things and I am left with a lot of questions. Do you know of any other good sources that go a bit deeper into rails routing that you can recommend? No worries if not, I can google search it - just thought i'd ask the master :)

Comment: Rails creates helpers/methods from the resources defined in Routes.rb. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622826/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-rails-routes-prefix

Comment: There is a really good book about ROR https://www.amazon.com/Agile-Web-Development-Rails-5-1/dp/1680502514

Comment: Thanks so much Tekkla. This really helps. I hope you have a great weekend, and just know you made someone's life better today with your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you should not use the url in the form_tag but the controller action. 
Let's say you've got a view called my_form.html.erb and a submit_form method in your soundcloud_controller.rb

```
def submit_form
  params[:soundcloud_url] your logic
end
```

I'd set up the routes like this:

```
get 'soundcloud_query' => 'soundcloud_query#my_form'  // didn't want to use 'resources' but it doesn't matter
post 'soundcloud_query' => 'soundcloud_query#submit_form'
```

The form would then look like:

```
<%= form_for :this_doesnt_matter, action: :submit_form do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :soundcloud_url %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer mike! I am a bit confused. Are you ddefining #my_form as an action? Also, when you make the post request like that, how does the rails router know which page to go to  when you hit submit?

Comment: when you hit submit you don't directly go to a page, you need to define a redirect in your controller, usually redirect_to :back - to stay on the current page
my_form is the view with your form - my_form.html.erb in soundcloud_query folder

to clear things up maybe:
in routes set up like this, 'get' takes a view (my_form) as a "parameter" and 'post' takes a controller method (submit_form)